# Можно сделать чтобы AJAX работал для локальных страниц в UIWebView iOS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ios

Добрый день. Необходимо обернуть мобильный сайт в нативное приложение для iOS. Сайт активно использует AJAX с обращением к удалённому серверу. Простое открытие index.html в UIWebView не работает. Возможно я понял политики браузера не разрешают обращение в сеть для локально хранимых страниц. Можно как-то сделать чтобы локальные страницы с AJAX открывались?

Comment: давайте подробнее. открытие локального index.html в UIWebView должно работать. Оно у вас вообще не работает? тогда начните в того, что проверьте путь. или работает, но Ajax не отрабатывает?

Comment: Сам html открывается, но ajax не отрабатывает. Страница вся на ajax построена, поэтому на экране пустое поле и 3 статических ссылки. Всё что ajax'ом загружается - пустое.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сафари консоли. может там что то появится.